# How to get the diskdrive hardware id in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the disk-drive hardware ID in C# ?

I tried **System.Management**, but I think this is only for *processor ID*.

I need the hardware ID that we find in cmd by typing `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`!